# Gmail conversation replies displayed in mailbox

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

Is it possible to display all the replies in an email thread in the mailbox, such as how Outlook does it:

[image: Conversation replies]

Answer (score 1):

There are those **3 dots** for that and after pressing them it will roll out:

[image: 1]